# IIS 8( windows server 2012) cannot run batch file

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, iis, iis-8

Im hosting an asp.net application in IIS8 on windows server 2012.
this application suppose to execute an batch file.

it works perfect if i execute the application with visual studio in debug mode. but when i upload it to the IIS the application cant execute the batch file.

i tried to change the batch file with exe file. same problem.

the batch file suppose to execute from the application(WCF application) that in the IIS:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\path";
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\executer.bat";
                proc.Start();
                proc.Close();
```

please help,

Comment: You need to provide considerably more detail on exactly how this batch file is supposed to be executed. Is it called from an ASP.NET page? Is it part of, perhaps, a web service? There's just not enough here to allow us to offer much help.

Comment: i added more details.

Comment: If you are certain the batch file isn't firing, then I'd put some try-catch blocks around the code that fires it and try to get some logging information established. On a server, you are most likely dealing with permissions issues wherein the account context running the site doesn't have access to the batch file host path.

Comment: i added try-couch. nothing writen into the log files.
any way, i think its premissions issue too. but dont know how to solve it. any idea?

Comment: Grant permissions to the account context running the site to the folder hosting the batch file.

Comment: Read/Execute minimally. I'm guessing right now that the relevant account context has *no* permissions to that folder. A tool like ProcMon might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem you are experiencing is due to permissions. You need to check what account the IIS Application Pool that your app is running under is configured for and whether that account has rights to run your batch file or the commands within that batch file.

When running in Visual Studio you're likely running IIS Express as the interactive user.

When running under IIS by default you're running under `ApplicationPoolUser` identity which has no rights to execute code, has no file access or anything else. Unless you've explicitly set a different account with appropriate file access rights to the batch file, and rights to execute the commands inside of the batch file, you won't be able to run the batch file from within IIS. To change that change the Application Pool user identity to a user that does have rights to both read and execute the batch file on disk and has any rights required to run what's executing in the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any folder or file accessed by your application have permissions granted to the AppPoolUser account. It is also important to check your applications resource folders too. For example, if you are writing logs, make sure you give the appPool user account enough permission to write to that file.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine . May be there is some issue in batch file i faced before .My batch file is

```
start "" BATCHLOG.exe
```

where **BATCHLOG.exe** is the executable

Some times batchfile named only

**BATCHLOG.exe**

does not work correctly on windows scheduler so may be in that case of yours